# some of columns in datagridview is readonly, but I need to change cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview, and it's datasource is from a datatable which combined three different tables.
In this datagridview, I set several columns as readonly = true;
And if I receive a telegraphic message, I need to update the value of these cell (readonly = true)
Sometimes, it show mistake: NullReferenceException
I'm not sure it's because I update cell value which is readonly or not
Below is my code, please help me

```
private void UpdateTrialSeqValue(string strProduct, string strBuy, string strSell,  string strBuy1Qty, string strSell1Qty)
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed && dgvWSettingAll != null)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateTrialSeqValue(strProduct, strBuy, strSell, strBuy1Qty, strSell1Qty)));
                return;
            }

            lock (Update_Flag)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSettingAll.Rows)
                {
                    if(row.Index >= 0)
                    {
                        string product = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Colproduct"].Value);
                        if (product == strProduct)
                        {
                            row.Cells["ColBuyQty"].Value = strBuy1Qty;
                            row.Cells["ColBuyPrice"].Value = strBuy;
                            row.Cells["ColSellPrice"].Value = strSell;
                            row.Cells["ColSellQty"].Value = strSell1Qty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have the data in a datatable why don't you simply update that datatable with new/changed data?

Comment: I have several function to update data in different columns which is readonly. I had tried use datatable to update data but one of function made it crashed.

Comment: Then try to fix those crashs. The workaround you try here is presumably worse.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException you are encountering may be due to accessing a read-only cell. To avoid this exception, you can check if a cell is read-only before updating its value:

```
private void UpdateTrialSeqValue(string strProduct, string strBuy, string 
strSell, string strBuy1Qty, string strSell1Qty)
{
if (!this.IsDisposed && dgvWSettingAll != null)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateTrialSeqValue(strProduct, 
strBuy, strSell, strBuy1Qty, strSell1Qty)));
        return;
    }

    lock (Update_Flag)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSettingAll.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index >= 0)
            {
                string product = 
 Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Colproduct"].Value);
                if (product == strProduct)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell buyQtyCell = row.Cells["ColBuyQty"];
                    DataGridViewCell buyPriceCell = row.Cells["ColBuyPrice"];
                    DataGridViewCell sellQtyCell = row.Cells["ColSellQty"];
                    DataGridViewCell sellPriceCell = 
row.Cells["ColSellPrice"];

                    if (!buyQtyCell.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        buyQtyCell.Value = strBuy1Qty;
                    }

                    if (!buyPriceCell.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        buyPriceCell.Value = strBuy;
                    }

                    if (!sellQtyCell.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        sellQtyCell.Value = strSell1Qty;
                    }

                    if (!sellPriceCell.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        sellPriceCell.Value = strSell;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your helping. But I need these columns to be readonly. At the same time can update new data

Answer (score 0):

### Use property DataSource!

When programmers use a DataGridView, they quite often tend to fiddle with the values in the cells directly. It is way easier to use property DataGridView.DataSource.

### class Pricess

Apparently your DataGridView has to show a table of Products, each Product showing a Name, buying Price and Qty and selling Price and Qty. Something like this:

```
class QtyPrice // TODO: invent a proper name
{
    public int Qty {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}

class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public QtyPrice BuyValue {get; set;}
    public QtyPrice SellValue {get; set;}

    ... // if needed, other properties
}
```

If your prices and quantity are not numbers but strings, you'll need to create extra methods to convert the strings to the proper numbers.

Give the class an (extra) constructor:

```
public Product (string name, string buyQtyText, string buyPriceText,
                             string sellQtyText, string sellPriceText)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.BuyValue = this.CreateBuyPrice(buyQtyText, buyPriceText);
    this.SellValue = this.CreateSellPrice(sellQtyText, sellPriceText);
```

}

You know the formats of your buy and sell strings, so I'll leave the implementation of the Create... to you.

### Displaying the data in the DataGridView

Using windows designer you have added the DataGridView and the five columns that you want to show. You can also define how each column should display the numbers. You will probably want to right align the numbers, and show the prices with a currency and two decimals.

In the constructor of your form you define which column should show which property:

```
public MyForm()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // define which column should show which property
    this.ColProductName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ColBuyValue.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.BuyValue.Qty);
    this.ColBuyPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.BuyValue.Price);

    this.ColSellQty.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.SellValue.Qty);
    this.ColSellPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.SellValue.Price);
}
```

You can also do this in the designer, but if you do it in the constructor, and later  you decide to change the names of the properties, the compiler will complain if you forget to change the names here.

Of course you will need a property to fetch the data that must be shown

```
public IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay(...) {...}
```

Implementation is out of scope of the question, so I'll leave that to you.

After all this work, displaying the Products in the DataGridView will be a one liner:

```
this.dgvProducts.DataSource = this.FetchProductsToDisplay(...).ToList();
```

The Products will be displayed read only. However, your DataGridView needs to be updatable. The easiest method for this will be to use a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=net-8.0) instead of a simple List

```
private BindingList<Products> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => this.dgvProducts.DataSource;
    set => this.dgvProducts.DataSource = value;
}
```

To display the initial Products, for instance while form loading:

```
private void DisplayInitialProducts()
{
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(this.FetchProductsToDisplay().ToList());
}
```

To update one of the displayed Products:

```
public void UpdateProductDisplay(Product productData)
{
    // find the Product that must be updated
    Product productToUpdate = this.DisplayedProducts
        .Where(product => product.Name == productData.Name)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    productToUpdate.BuyValue = productData.BuyValue;
    productToUpdate.SellValue = productData.SellValue;
}
```

The BindingList knows that the values are being updated, and will notify the DataGridView to update the changed values.

Your UpdateTrialSeqValue will need to translate the strings into a Product, and call this method.

### Changes made by the operator

Your program doesn't allow the operator to change the displayed Products. If you need in future a program where the operator can change the data, the following might be useful:

Scenario: Operator changes values of cells, adds some new Products, and removes some products. Then he presses the "Apply Now" button, to indicate that he has finished changing the Products.

```
public void OnButtonApplyNow_Pressed(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<Product> editedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;
    this.UpdateProducts(editedProducts);
    // compares the edited products with the original products
    // and updates the changes
}
```

To access the Products in the current cell or in the selected cells:

```
private Product CurrentProduct => (Product)this.dgvProducts.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

private IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts => this.dgvProducts.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();
```

Usage:

```
private void SaveSelectedProducts()
{
    List<Product> selectedProducts = this.SelectedProducts.ToList();
    this.Save(selectedProducts);
}
```

### Conclusion

By using the DataSource of the DataGridView instead of fiddling with the cells directly, you separate the data from how it is displayed. This might mean more initial code, but this code will be highly reusable, easy to understand and to unit test, easy to change.

And did you notice that most methods and properties I wrote are one liners?